# writing from list to text file

Tags: java, io

I have created atext file encoder using java and I have added the words from the text to a  list 
.
Now for decoding program I need that list which I used in encoding program I have used the reference variable word for it. I cant understand how to use that list in the decoding program. How to import it

Comment: Please show your code - specifically the code you used for exporting and the contents of the file - or a small example file.

Comment: Search for java file writer and you'll find lots of examples. Iterate through your list, write each entry in the list to the file on its own line, and then close it

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example that writes a `List` to a `File` then read the `File` to regenerate the `List`. It then checks that the two are the same.

The code uses `File.createTempFile` and `File.deleteOnExit` to prevent creating random files everywhere while using this example. Obviously this needs to be replaced with the real location of the store file:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    final List<String> myList = new LinkedList<>();
    myList.add("Some");
    myList.add("Random");
    myList.add("Content");
    myList.add("Some");
    final File file = File.createTempFile("testProgram", ".list");
    file.deleteOnExit();
    writeToFile(myList, file);
    final List<String> myList2 = readFromFile(file);
    System.out.println(myList);
    System.out.println(myList2);
    if (myList.equals(myList2)) {
        System.out.println("List read is the same as the list written");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Something has gone wrong...");
    }
}

public static void writeToFile(final List<String> list, final File file) throws IOException {
    try (final BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file))) {
        for (final String line : list) {
            bw.append(line);
            bw.newLine();
        }
    }
}

public static List<String> readFromFile(final File file) throws IOException {
    final List<String> content = new LinkedList<>();
    try (final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            content.add(line);
        }
    }
    return content;
}
```

Alternatively you can use the Java serialization api to write the `List` to a file as binary content and read it back. This will be faster but the file will contain gibberish (non human readable content).

```
public static void writeToFile(final List<String> list, final File file) throws IOException {
    try (final ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file))) {
        oos.writeObject(list);
    }
}

public static List<String> readFromFile(final File file) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    try (final ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file))) {
        return (List<String>) ois.readObject();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also use `Files.readAllLines()` and `Files.write()` instead of iterating on `BufferedWriter` and `BufferedReader`.